# NetSuite Sandbox Account to Live Deployment

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

We have worked on NetSuite SuiteBuilder Application where, we do.

- We created new theme.
- New Layouts.
- New Templates.
- SuiteScript files.
- Uploaded different images/videos etc.
- Created New Custom Fields in the Application accessible in different
  other parts.
- Created New SSP Application and etc.

Now my point is that, how to transfer all these things into live environment.
Without loosing Live Environment Data.

Is it possible to keep backup of Live Files and then move development files into live and we can test it.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In the past, I've used a SuiteBundle/package to transfer Sandbox data to Production. You'll have to be careful what you transfer as not to duplicate any information or fields.

Comment: If I create SuiteBundle, then I will lost any file ??